# ERROR: MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python-poetry

I have successfully done the following in my Mac:

1. pyenv install 3.8.13
2. installed Poetry
3. poetry env use 3.8.13

But when I do "poetry install", it's failing with "ERROR: MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform".

What is causing this poetry failure? Is my Mac not supporting this version of wheel?

My pyproject.toml contains `MarkupSafe = "2.0.1"`.

I already tried upgrading pip with "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" but still the same error.